# face foto at home with mobile-tablet

Tags: shooting-technique

I don't know anything from fotos techniques.I hope to help me.I take mirror and I see that I am a handsome man. I attract many woman's.I can't with easy way managed to have a good foto.In the most of the fotos I am ungly. I can't understand why this happens. I don't use software's on my devices not after when i have the image.Should I?What's your opinion to achieve a nice foto of my face with those devices?It's my first visit on this forum I was health and many other in case this question is off close it but i would like to give me a nice answer because you are experts.Thanks in advance

Comment: Get someone else to take the photo, from at least twice the distance. Tablets/phones have very wide lenses which make faces look very 'pointy' from up close.

Answer (score 0):

The light inside is not as good as outside in daylight.

However, direct sunlight creates strong shadows which often don't look good for photos of the face.

Therefore - take your photo outside, on a sunny day, but stand in the shade and make sure the scene behind you is shaded. For example, find a building wall that is in shade and take the photo there.

Comment: Or find a north-facing window (in the northern hemisphere) during the day and stand facing the window. The indirect light through the window tends to be flattering.